# PHP exec to change Windows password with IIS

Tags: php, windows, passwords, cmd, exec

is there anyway to allow PHP to run "exec ("net user Jason 123") on Windows 7 with IIS? I have made the appPool that is running my site run with the Admin user, and the site is setup to use the Admin user...so it should have full rights? And in the test I see two green ticks. But for some reason it still wont change the password, is there anyway I can test to see what the problem is? Or does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: It worked on a different webserver, although ive forgotten what the name of that server was, and I would prefer to use IIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a windows server you can use [php's COM/.NET extension](http://docs.php.net/com) which makes the 
[IADsUser::ChangePassword method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746341%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) available to your script.

```
try {
    //$user = new COM("WinNT://./volker,user");
    $user = new COM("WinNT://domainname/accountname,user");
    $user->ChangePassword('oldpass', 'newpass');
}
catch(com_exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
    die('no no no');
}
```

Comment: Im running IIS of Windows 7 Ultimate x64, So im not on a domian...would this still work?

Comment: If just tested it on my standalone Windows7 professional x64 notebook and it worked. But since you have to insert the username into the string for `new COM` you should look around for a good filter/escape function for valid usernames.

Comment: sorry im a little bit confused with: $user = new COM("WinNT://domainname/accountname,user");  If I have an account "Jason" with a password "123" on a computer called "Russell-Server"....what would go where? "user" is confusing me in the quoted line

Comment: That would be `$user = new COM("WinNT://./Jason,user");` if that script is executed on `Russell-Serve` since `.` stands for `local machine`